# Joomla 3.2.3 Admin Menu Disappeared

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I've just installed a new Joomla 3.2.3 without any problems.

After loggin out and in again in the adminstrator area, I can see the top menu buttons disappeared!

I have re-installed Joomla again using the extensions manager but it didn't work out. Now, I have uploaded all the files again using FTP. It did not work either.

I know other users experienced the same problem, can anyone share some ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you logged in as super admin? Do all top menu items disappear?

Comment: Yes, I was logged in as super admin. The only solution that worked for me (so far) was to delete the whole site and database and reinstall it over again.

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in console?

Comment: @di3sel no, all I could see were the menus had gone.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has to do with Joomla's ACL

You logged in as Super User / Administrator and there is no admin menu and the page seems unformatted?

This is the solution that worked for me:

A few hours earlier I had edited the "Special" access level.
It seems this is indeed a Special access level that cannot be altered or the admin section will be broken.

So you have to go into MySQL phpMyAdmin or whatever way you prefer to handle the db
and look for the *dbname*_viewlevels table on your joomla's database

Look for **ID 3** which corresponds to the "Special" access level.
If it's name has been altered change it back to Special

Then under the "rules" tab make sure the value "8" is present.
Your rules value should look like [8], or [6,8], depending.
In my case and comparing with other Joomla installations db I have set the value to [6,3,8] as having it as only [8] fixed the Super User template, but the users with Administrator ACL were still broken.

Save, log out of your admin area and log back in, and the backend should be completely restored.

~mav

Answer (score 1):

I've also had the same issue. I upgraded from 3.2.2 to 3.2.3 and followed the same steps above and all of my menus are gone. There are no errors. The front-end of the site is fine but I can't edit or make any changes in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm commenting after so many years, cause I just had the same problem on online joomla management on www.cloudaccess.net.
This happened to me after editing the "Special" access level and I don't have access to php so here is what I had to do:

1. go to https://mywebsite.joomla.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=level&layout=edit&id=3
2. check options: Manager, Author, Super Users
3. as I couldn't save the changes I needed to edit the website source code using examine the item (I think this is how it's called in English) and paste somewhere the button:

```html
  <button onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('level.apply');" class="btn btn-small button-apply btn-success">
    <span class="icon-apply icon-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    Save</button>
```

4. click the pasted button to save changes and everything should be fine again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me and i found it REALLY funny that i had to use Chrome's INSPECT feature to create a button LOL

go to https://mywebsite.joomla.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=level&layout=edit&id=3

check options: Manager, Author, Super Users

as I couldn't save the changes I needed to edit the website source code using examine the item (I think this is how it's called in English) and paste somewhere the button:

Save

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please also join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and share your insights there too.